# What is the difference between "clicked", "browse", and "productive" in the EXM report?

Tags: exm

Can anyone tell me the differences between *clicked*, *browse*, and *productive* in the report (recepients behavior) in Email Experience Manager?

[image]

I have read the explanation from [sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/creating_and_editing_messages/editing_messages/engagement_plans_for_email_campaigns) but i am still confused :/

Answer (score 2):

**Clicked** means that the recipient clicked on a link from the email and entered the site.

**Browsed** means that the user visited multiple pages in their visit.

**Productive** means that the visitor generated engagement value.